# Guardar registros de una lista evitando los duplicados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, insert

espero puedan apoyarme con ésta duda que tengo.

Estoy intentando hacer una carga masiva (adjuntar un excel, que la info se guarde en una lista y ésta lista se guarde en la BD) y por ahora eso lo hace bien, pero el problema es cuando hay un dato repetido. Si hay un dato repetido, simplemente manda error y no inserta nada a la BD.

Lo que me gustaría es poder insertar los registros que no estén duplicados. El dato que se evaluaría (no se debería repetir) sería el de **Orden_IdProduction**

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**:
Ya estuve investigando, hago una consulta a la tabla de la base de datos y luego esa información la meto en una lista, ahora lo que intento es comparar las dos listas y que los valores de la list1 que no esten en list2, me los devuelva en una nueva lista para poder insertarlos peeero no he encontrado como :'(

Ya estuve usando Intersect, Except, ExceptBy y DistinctBy. Con el DistinctBy me elimina los repetidos y lo que quiero es que me deje los no repetidos para insertarlos. El Except así como lo tengo en mi código, si me muestra los Id que no están duplicados pero no me manda todos los campos.

Mi código es éste...

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EnviarDatos([FromForm] IFormFile ArchivoExcel)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("NombreDelServidor; DataBase=DB_ControlProduccionDEV; user id=***; password=***; Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA;
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Tb_OrdenProduccion;";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlDA.Fill(dataTable);

        List<Ordenes> listDB = new List<Ordenes>();
        listDB = (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
                  select new Ordenes()
                  {
                      Orden_IdProduction = dr["Orden_IdProduction"].ToString(),
                      Orden_ItemNumber = dr["Orden_ItemNumber"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Quantity = dr["Orden_Quantity"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Reportremainder = dr["Orden_Reportremainder"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Job = dr["Orden_Job"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Type = dr["Orden_Type"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Status = dr["Orden_Status"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Delivery = dr["Orden_Delivery"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Pool = dr["Orden_Pool"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Matcomp = dr["Orden_Matcomp"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Averagecost = dr["Orden_Averagecost"].ToString(),
                      Orden_Jobs = dr["Orden_Jobs"].ToString()
                  }).ToList();

        Stream stream = ArchivoExcel.OpenReadStream();
        IWorkbook? myExcel = null;

        if (Path.GetExtension(ArchivoExcel.FileName) == ".xlsx")
        {
            myExcel = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            myExcel = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
        }

        ISheet hojaExcel = myExcel.GetSheetAt(0);

        int cantidadFilas = hojaExcel.LastRowNum;

        List<Ordenes> listOrders = new List<Ordenes>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadFilas; i++)
        {
            IRow fila = hojaExcel.GetRow(i);
            listOrders.Add(new Ordenes
            {
                Orden_IdProduction = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(),
                Orden_ItemNumber = fila.GetCell(1).ToString(),
                Orden_Quantity = fila.GetCell(2).ToString(),
                Orden_Reportremainder = fila.GetCell(3).ToString(),
                Orden_Job = fila.GetCell(4).ToString(),
                Orden_Type = fila.GetCell(5).ToString(),
                Orden_Status = fila.GetCell(6).ToString(),
                Orden_Delivery = fila.GetCell(7).ToString(),
                Orden_Pool = fila.GetCell(8).ToString(),
                Orden_Matcomp = fila.GetCell(9).ToString(),
                Orden_Averagecost = fila.GetCell(10).ToString(),
                Orden_Jobs = fila.GetCell(11).ToString()
            });
        }

        //var listFinal = listOrders.Concat(listDB).ToList();
        //listFinal = listFinal.DistinctBy(x => x.Orden_IdProduction).ToList();

        List<string> listFinal = listOrders.Select(listOrders => listOrders.Orden_IdProduction).Except(listDB.AsEnumerable().Select(listDB => listDB.Orden_IdProduction)).ToList();

        _dbContext.BulkInsert(listFinal);

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = "La carga masiva se ejecutó con éxito"});
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Graciaaas!

Comment: Para hacerlo, entiendo que seria justo despues del For, para que la lista, ya completa, sea evaluada y se eliminen los registros duplicados.
// Eliminar registros duplicados en el campo "Orden_IdProduction"

    listOrders = listOrders.DistinctBy(x => x.Orden_IdProduction).ToList();

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya estuve investigando y revisando la solución que me compartes pero con eso sólo se evalua si en esa lista existen los valores duplicados y elimina los que sí, pero yo debo comparar esa lista con lo que ya está en la BD :( @pcandido

Comment: Con el distinct evalúas si la lista tiene duplicados antes de insertar en la base de datos, si quieres evaluar si ya está registrado, necesitas hacer un método que evalúe directamente en tu base de datos antes de hacer el insert

Comment: @Daniel Ya actualicé mi pregunta, lo que estoy haciendo es consultar la info de la bd, después agregarlo a una lista y ahora intento comparar las dos listas pero no tengo éxito :(

Comment: List<string> list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
//  lista list3 que contendrá solo los valores de list1 que no están en list2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a las respuestas de @pcandido tuve una idea de cómo solicionar mi problema, al final, la línea quedó así:

```
List<Ordenes> listFinal = listOrders.ExceptBy(listDB.Select(x => x.Orden_IdProduction), x => x.Orden_IdProduction).ToList();
```

Se los dejo por si a alguien más le sirve.

Answer (score 1):

Justo después del For

```
// Eliminar registros duplicados en el campo "Orden_IdProduction"
listOrders = listOrders.DistinctBy(x => x.Orden_IdProduction).ToList();
```